# Best method to create custom NewForm / EditForm

Tags: 2010, list, feature-receiver

I am new to sharepoint development and need to create some custom NewForm/EditForms for a new custom list I am creating.  It seems like I have two choices:

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/sharepoint-2010-create-and-update-list-forms-programmatically/

Basically, it seems like I can either create the form in sharepoint designer, and then save the entire .aspx and include that in my solution -- or I can add a Feature receiver to make the changes.  Or is there another way to do it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use the first method - Create the Form in SPD, save it in .aspx and include it in a List definition feature.

**Benefits**

1. Creating the form in SPD and doing the modifications required are pretty much easy. For eg.- Adding a list view web part or modifying an XSLT would be quiet easier in SPD.
2. Now, adding .aspx in a list definition in VS and deploying it as a feature should be considered good enough to move it across environments. (DEV -> TEST -> PROD).

Whatever method you have implemented to customize in SharePoint comes handy only if it is packaged and ready to use as a WSP.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd option is InfoPath - if you're in such a position in which you can enable the SharePoint -> InfoPath integration features. Especially useful if forms will later be maintained by staff who are more familiar with Word or Office as the UI will be very familiar to them.

Comment: Be aware that InfoPath forms don't play nice with managed metadata.

Comment: InfoPath will not be supported in further Editions of SharePoint

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Deepu's explanation in general.

For more details rather, you need to consider, assuming you build a WSP package via VS2010:

- Your own custom list?  - if yes, you could do it declaratively in the
  List Definition (is a bitch to do that XML declaratively for the
  views  - but is doable).
- Another list?  - use Deepu's explanation with the caveat that you
  should probably use the a MODULE in VS to deploy it and then update
  that list's informaiton to point to your new file.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius