# Customize list new/edit form page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form, branding

Could someone outline the process of creating a page with a customized list form? I followed [this guide](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=987) to override the list form template, but this also customizes the built-in form pages/dialogs. I want the admin pages/dialogs untouched, and use custom forms only an application page I create myself. The goal is to provide a fully branded form that matches the rest of the site. Also, since this is a solution that's going to be deployed I want programmatic solutions, i.e. I don't want to use SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace edit and new forms for lists and libraries with developed by you using module and setting it as default new and edit forms. 
You can check [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34171/best-method-to-create-custom-newform-editform) for more details.
But I if you want develop new and edit forms with custom look easier, check [SPForm tool](http://spform.com/), you can use editor, javascript and css styles to adjust completely new look for list and libraries forms.